# Show only some choices for ModelForm field

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have the following model

```
class MyChoiceModel(models.Model):
    mychoices = (('ChoiceA', 'ChoiceA'), ('ChoiceB', 'ChoiceB'))
```

and the following ModelForm

```
class MyChoiceModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #...
    class Meta:
        model = MyChoiceModel
        fields = ('mychoices', )
```

Now, the user can select all types of choices (`ChoiceA` and `ChoiceB`).
What I want now is that certain choice values won't be displayed.

How can I filter the available choices from `mychoices` such that for example only `ChoiceA` would be selectable by the user and - under other circumstances - only `ChoiceB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this: here is a way that i have

```
def CustomChoiceList():
    # return custom choices

class MyChoiceModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = { 'mychoices': CustomChoiceList() }
```

if you need more control, or access to the model look at creating a `forms.ModelChoiceField)`

eg:

```
class CustomChoices(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        # return some obj.title, or whatever in your object as the label to show
```

then in the ModelForm

```
mychoices = CustomChoices(required=True, queryset=YourModelYouWant.objects.filter(...))
```